# Any other airlines that offer a non-stop Madrid-Cairo flight?

Tags: air-travel, budget, planning, flight-search-engines, madrid

I can only find EgyptAir offering a non-stop flight from MAD-CAI.

Are there other options?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can be a) impossible to answer -- maybe tomorrow another airline will start flying the route so it can be too broad but also how on earth do you prove a negative? Sure, ExpertFlyer and Skyscanner both only shows Egyptair on any random day but ... b) it can be WANTA, c) or we could post how to search for a flight between a pair of cities but that'd be a duplicate for sure we have tools questions by the dozens.

Answer (score 3):

Not as of right now.

Madrid Barajas' official website lists all non-stop destinations and airlines flying them. It lists only EgyptAir against "El Cairo" (the Spanish name for the city).

http://www.aena.es/en/madrid-barajas-airport/airport-destinations.html#E